# PHP Laravel insert to table using foreach

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this post request data

```
 array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "oZ5OjnWU4svOPPFXMrzkDIBau92yIxd7l1Onn1EN"
  "orderId" => "2"
  "product_id" => array:3 [▼
     0 => "111"
     1 => "222"
     2 => "333"
   ]
    "product_price" => array:3 [▼
       0 => "150.00"
       1 => "1800.00"
       2 => "800.50"
     ]
     "discount" => "10.00"
     "status" => "SUCCESS"
      ]
```

and I'm trying to save it to my table using this code.

```
  public function upsellStore( Request $request ) {

    $input = $request->all();
    foreach($input['product_id'] as $id ) {
        $order = new OrderProduct;
        $order->orderid = $input['orderId'];
        $order->discount = $input['discount'];
        $order->status = $input['status'];
        $order->product_id = $id;
        $order->product_price = $input['product_price'];
        $order->save();
    }

    return $order;

}
```

however I'm not sure how to save it. `product_id` and `product_price` should be aligned so the output of this save should be something like this

```
   

       <table>
       <tbody>
       <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
      <th>Product ID</th>
         <th>Price</th>
            <th>Discount</th>
            <th>Status</th>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
       <tbody>
       <tr>
   <td>1</td>
      <td>111</td>
         <td>150.00</td>
            <td>10.00</td>
             <td>SUCCESS</td>
       </tr>

      <tr>
   <td>1</td>
      <td>222</td>
         <td>1800.00</td>
            <td>10.00</td>
                    <td>SUCCESS</td>
       </tr>


       <!-- and so on... -->
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pablo. Best regards. Your product_price is an array, therefore you can't do:

`$order->product_price = $input['product_price'];`

I would make a different approach in the view that contains the form, in order to be sure that the array of product_id matches the size/sequence of product_price (better readability/maintenance).

But to solve the problem the way you presented, you need to get the key of product_id, and use that key to retrieve the price, like this:

> ```
> foreach($input['product_id'] as $key => $id ) {
>     $order = new OrderProduct;
>     $order->orderid = $input['orderId'];
>     $order->discount = $input['discount'];
>     $order->status = $input['status'];
>     $order->product_id = $id;
>     $order->product_price = $input['product_price'][$key];
>     $order->save();
> }
> ```